# Getting static analysis of GitHub repositories

Tags: github, repository, static-analysis, codacy

thank you all for taking the time reading my post. I have an assignment where I have to do static analysis for various github repositories. The tool I found is Codacy (I'm open to recommendations though) and I'm trying to see how I can use it using the api it offers. As I was reading the documentation I found out that I can only analyze repositories that I own or I have in my organization but I need it for repositories that are not mine. Do you know if there is another way to get those repositories? I also thought to clone the repositories and creating a private one on my account but I am not sure if it's possible or if it's right to do. I am open to suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to try a different tool.  Depending on the language, there can be many tools for static analysis available.

Comment: Because I am dealing with multiple languages I am looking for one that covers most of them (and its free).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.